# PHP Output buffering contains something before script starts

Tags: php, output-buffering

i have a site, where i buffer some output with

```
ob_start();
...
```

and it worked fine until today i updated my debian from an older **php5.3** to the latest **php5.3.3-7**+squeeze8
Now i sometimes have something in the output buffer before i call it the first time

please don't answer things like

> "header must be called before any output is sent."
>   (I know, I work a lot with output buffers)

when i set an extra ob_get_clean(); at the very first line of my script, it works

```
<?
ob_get_clean();
```

it seems, like php is creating some output beforehand
if i put the first line

```
<? print_r(ob_get_clean()); ?>
```

then i see, that there is an empty string already in the buffer:

> ""

on all other pages it isn't, there ob_get_clean(); contains

> null

Comment: Seen this before .... you don't see it but there is something there ... delete the file and recreate it  ... if possible use another editor or just notepad ...

Comment: related to [Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php), see the hexeditor thing and outbut buffering section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it:

i had no invisible character in front, it was something different: i called ob_end_clean() one time too much:

this was my code, inside a function i call:

```
function print_something(){
ob_start();

echo some stuff...

echo ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean(); // this was the bug! 
}
```

it seems, that you can clear your main output buffer ;)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible you have some " " in front of your `<?php` somewhere? or wrong file encoding issue its usually some kind of that nature, check your files and include files.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i sometimes have something in the output buffer before i call it
>   the first time

It'll be much easier if you give us some info about that mysterious data.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a case of BOM character?
more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)