# A strange (space) before ajax.reponseText

Tags: php, ajax

I seen a strange (space) before response I got from Ajax.response text. Each time i fire my Ajax it sends some variables and activates php script and returns a string as Ajax.response text.

After some tinkering i found that even if i echo  "nothing" I get a space before this static string too. what can cause this strange thing to happen ?

Ajax declaration :

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open(meth, url, true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
    return true;    
}
}
```

PHP script :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pattern']))   
{     
echo "nothing" ;
exit();
}?>
```

My Observations :

1. No effect after removing exit function.
2. No space before php and ajax decalration.
3. Firebug says " nothing".
4. Tried in all browsers.

Comment: Perhaps an utf8 BOM? Make sure your php file is saved without it.

Comment: Check if there is `auto_prepend_file ` in `php.ini`. Also look at [http://stackoverflow.com/q/10072569/5962802](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10072569/5962802)

Comment: Checked auto_prepend_file ..... no effect but still thank you any help is appreciated. learned something new.

Comment: php files are saved without  utf8 inside php files

Comment: you might have left some a newline after closing the php tag on some of your file. this might be an issue

Comment: Yes sir i forget to add that  i also checked for spaces after and before php tags too .